# how to properly refactor this function into another file? django

Tags: python, django, exception, return, try-catch

I have a `try` and `except` which is used super often, so I am thinking of taking it out and make it into a `function` in other file but I cannot seem to make it work.

Can someone please give me a hand?

this is the code which I use really really often

```
    try:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, email=data['email'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return JSONresponse(False, e.message)
```

I tried making it into another file and did it this way

```
def auth_token(data):
    try:
        return get_object_or_404(User, email=data['email'])
    except Exception as e:
        return JSONresponse({'status': False})
```

then when I call `auth_token` I did it this way in another way and of course I did import it

```
user = auth_token(data)
```

I can understand this would then return me `JSONresponse({'status': False})` and I tried using `raise` and it would tell me that I can't use `JSONresponse`

Can someone give me an idea how this can be done?

Comment: How did you import it? I think it related to the import, you might need to import the JsonResponse
`from django.http import JsonResponse`
and change it into
`return JsonResponse({'status': False})`

Comment: The try and except branches return two different types (User/JSONResponse), that's not a good design choice..

Comment: @adeealamsz yes I did import that

Comment: @thebjorn what would be a good way though?

Comment: I don't think you correctly define it, see the case, you define it All uppercase for word JSON, while based on django it should be `JsonResponse` not `JSONresponse` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: instead of returning `return JSONresponse({'status': False})` do a `raise` this should point you in the right direction of what might go wrong, or you could log it `logger.exception("something went wrong")` that should give you the error and the traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to use as simple parameters as possible (this makes your function easier to test).

What you're looking for in the exception case is something that can be sent from `auth_token` through your view:

```
def auth_token(email):  # this returns a User not a token..?
    try:
        return User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(JSONresponse({'status': False}))
```

Usage would then be:

```
def myview(request, ...):
    token = auth_token(data['email'])
    ...
```

Any `ImmediateHttpResponse` exception will escape the view and must be picked up by a middleware class.

Unfortunately, Django doesn't come with an `ImmediateHttpResponse` class, but TastyPie has one that we can steal. First the exception class:

```
class ImmediateHttpResponse(Exception):
    """This exception is used to interrupt the flow of processing to immediately
       return a custom HttpResponse.

       Common uses include::

           * for authentication (like digest/OAuth)
           * for throttling

       (from TastyPie).
    """
    _response = http.HttpResponse("Nothing provided.")

    def __init__(self, response):
        self._response = response

    @property
    def response(self):
        return self._response
```

then the middleware:

```
from myexceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse

class ImmediateHttpResponseMiddleware(object):
    """Middleware that handles ImmediateHttpResponse exceptions, allowing 
       us to return a response from deep in form handling code.
    """
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, ImmediateHttpResponse):
            return exception.response
        return None
```

This class must be added to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your `settings.py` file as `'mymiddleware.ImmediateHttpResponseMiddleware'`.

Comment: where should I create these two classes though? `ImmediateHttpResponse`, `ImmediateHttpResponseMiddleware`

Comment: Wherever you want.

Comment: I just tried it, still just returns as regular 404 page instead of `{'status': False}`

Comment: Sorry about that. The exception raised was a `Http404`, not a `User.DoesNotExist`.  I've fixed the code.

Comment: thanks for this, it's so helpful.  Finally can reuse it.  Thanks a lot

Comment: sorry to bother, but I thought of modifying it a bit and realized, this only works if `DoesNotExist` is caught.  Anyway I can modify so it catches anything and still throw json response? for example if it's `AttributeError`

Comment: that's what I thought so too but then it doesn't o.O
I also tried to use `Excetipion` instead of something like `AttributeError`, but it would only throw json response if `Excetipion` catches `DoesNotExist` anything else loads the 404 page.